# How to get json return value from php by javaScript / jquery?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json

This is my javaScript code :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#IMDB').click(function() {  
       var MovieID = $('#MovieID').val();

       $.post('action/action.php', { url: "http://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/"+MovieID
+"?append_to_response=credits,images&api_key=myapikey" }, function(data) {
           var aliases = data.aliases;  
           document.getElementById('GamesTitle').value = aliases;
       });
    });
});
```

and this my php code

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
    $url = $_POST['url'];
    $context = stream_context_create(['http' => ['user_agent' => 'API Test UA']]);
    $response = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
    $json = json_decode($response, true);
    foreach($json as $item){
        if($item['aliases'] !== null && $item['aliases'] !== 'O' && $item['aliases'] !== '1'){
            $aliases .= $item['aliases'];  // its give the result fine in php page
        }   
    }

    echo json_encode(array(
      'aliases' => $aliases
    ));
    return true;
```

but when i click my button to get all information its not getting anything.
and i dont get any error in console or anywhere so i can't find my problem.

and when i return value in php page it returns like this - >

O null null null null
{my result}
1

thats why i have to skip this O and 1 with

```
if($item['aliases'] !== null && $item['aliases'] !== 'O' && $item['aliases'] !== '1') {// .... now its ok }
```

if you remove this from php it will work fine. like this

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
    $url = $_POST['url'];

    echo json_encode(array(
      'aliases' => 'test' /// now its work fine
    ));
    return true;
```

Comment: `$.post` need to be `$.json`

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: $.json is not a function  - it return this error

Comment: Unclear. Please add the $response variable's returned data with this question.

Comment: Can you give an example of your expected response from your `php`?

Comment: i have edited my question

Comment: Your edit hasn't helped me at all. Can you give me an example of the json response you are trying to putout via `php` what information from the API should it have? Movie title? Images? What?

Comment: So what does that have to do with the themoviedb api? how are those related or linked?

Comment: the response from the api doesn't have the alias key

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add `."json"`...  like:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#IMDB').click(function() {  
   var MovieID = $('#MovieID').val();

   $.post('action/action.php', { url: "http://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/"+MovieID+"?append_to_response=credits,images&api_key=myapikey" }, function(data) {
       var aliases = data.aliases;  
       document.getElementById('GamesTitle').value = aliases;
   }, "json");
});
});
```

now the return `data` will be interpreted as JSON.

Comment: javascript code is ok! but the problem is in php page     when i remove this from php its works well ---- <code>$context = stream_context_create(['http' => ['user_agent' => 'API Test UA']]);
$response = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
$json = json_decode($response, true);
foreach($json as $item){
 if($item['aliases'] !== null && $item['aliases'] !== 'O' && $item['aliases'] !== '1'){
  $aliases .= $item['aliases'];
 } 
}</code>

Comment: ok now I understand.  you need to put all of your data being sent to `action.php`into a structure, then use `JSON.stringify()` and send that to php.  that is what it is looking for with `json_decode`.  here is the emca reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify